# TypeScript <string, BrowserWindow> tupple only allows to use parameter value: string | BrowserWindow on forEach method

Tags: typescript, electron

I want to acess the `string` and `BrowserWindow` values of tupple `<string, BrowserWindow>` on `.forEach()` tupple method, but its only allowed to acess the `string` value or `BrowserWindow`.

**Example**

```
let windows: [string, BrowserWindow]
windows.push('home', new BrowserWindow())

windows.forEach(function(value: string | BrowserWindow, index, array) {
    // Do stuff
})
```

I want to be able to acess `string` and `BrowserWindow` values, not `string` or `BrowserWindow`.

**Example**

```
let windows: [string, BrowserWindow]
windows.push('home', new BrowserWindow())

windows.forEach(function(valueString: string, valueWindow: BrowserWindow, index, array) {
   // Do stuff
})
```

Would having a `forEach()` inside a `forEach()`, using diferent values, be the best/only solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` is inherited from array and will iterate all elements of the tuple. Its callback parameter must then be a union of all possible elements in the array.

From my reading of the code, you don't really want a tuple, you probably want an array of tuples of type `[string, BrowserWindow]`

```
class BrowserWindow{}
let windows: [string, BrowserWindow][] = []
windows.push(['home', new BrowserWindow()])
/// use an arrow function with array parameter destructuring 
windows.forEach(([valueString, valueWindow], index, array) => {

})
```

Or if you really want just a single tuple and you want to access the constituents of the tuple, you can use array destructuring:

```
let windows: [string, BrowserWindow] = ['home', new BrowserWindow()];

let [valueString, valueWindow] = windows
```

Comment: Thanks! @Titian +1 So, let me see if I got this straight... A tuple its like a map but only have 1 key value item?